# creating object without parameters in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am currently new to Angular 4 Framework. I was facing difficulty to create an object in a component and initializing it as a new instance of the class. I have already imported the class into the component.ts file. Yet It is showing the error as expected 4 arguments but has 0. Can anyone please help.

My student class is:

```
export class Student {



  constructor(
    public _id: number,
    public first_name :string,
    public last_name: string,
    public email : string

  ){}
}
```

and the error is in the component file:

```
export class StudentNewComponent implements OnInit {
  newStudent= new Student();

  createStudentEvent= new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  create(){
      this.createStudentEvent.emit(this.newStudent);
      this.newStudent = new Student();
  }
}
```

In the above code segment, I am having error in the second line

> newStudent= new Student();

and last line

> this.newStudent = new Student();

I don't want to instantiate the newStudent because it is receiving the content from different component in the app

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
export class Student {
    constructor(
        public _id?: number,
        public first_name?: string,
        public last_name?: string,
        public email?: string
    ) { }
}
```

declare object like this `newStudent: Student = new Student();`

Comment: Thanks @Chandru, the error is gone in IDE but webpack failed to compile when using ng serve

Answer (score 0):

You can declare constructor arguments as optional, use this functionality in TypeScript by adding a ? to the end of parameters we want to be optional. For example, let’s say we want the last name parameter from above to be optional:

```
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName?: string) {
    if (lastName)
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    else
        return firstName;
}
let result1 = buildName("Bob");                  // works correctly now
let result2 = buildName("Bob", "Adams", "Sr.");  // error, too many parameters
let result3 = buildName("Bob", "Adams");         // ah, just right
```